# Help with type traits

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, type-traits, compile-time-constant

Suppose we have the following template class

```
template<typename T> class Wrap { /* ... */ };
```

We **can not change** `Wrap`. It is important.

Let there are classes derived from `Wrap<T>`. For example,

```
class NewInt  : public Wrap<int>     { /* ... */ };
class MyClass : public Wrap<myclass> { /* ... */ };
class Foo     : public Wrap<Bar>     { /* ... */ };
```

We **can not change** these classes too. All classes above is 3rd party. They are not mine.

I need the following compile time `type_traits`:

```
template<class T>
struct is_derived_from_Wrap { 
     static const bool value = /* */;
};
```

What do I need?

```
assert(is_derived_from_Wrap<Int>::value == true);  // Indeed I need static assert
assert(is_derived_from_Wrap<MyClass>::value == true);
assert(is_derived_from_Wrap<char>::value == false);
struct X {};
assert(is_derived_from_Wrap<X>::value == false);
```

Comment: But can you change `Int` and `MyClass`? :p

Comment: Wouldn't a better naming for your type traits be: `has_Wrap_for_base` ? Actually, MyClass is not a base of Wrap.

Comment: I'm confused. Ist it `int` or `Int`? And `myClass` or `MyClass`? Or are these distinct?

Comment: @dtrosset: Yes. You are right. My bad english.

Comment: @sbi: different classes.

Comment: @Alexey: I think I understand now what's up with that `MyClass`. What's with `Int`/`NewInt` then? Can you please be more precise?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using SFINAE but its kind of magical if you dont know whats going on...

```
template<typename T> class Wrap { };

struct myclass {};
struct X {};

class Int     : public Wrap<int>     { /* ... */ };
class MyClass : public Wrap<myclass> { /* ... */ };

template< typename X >
struct is_derived_from_Wrap
{
  struct true_type { char _[1]; };
  struct false_type { char _[2]; };

  template< typename U >
    static true_type test_sfinae( Wrap<U> * w);
  static false_type test_sfinae( ... );

  enum { value = sizeof( test_sfinae( (X*)(0) ) )==sizeof(true_type) };
};


#include <iostream>
#define test(X,Y) std::cout<<( #X " == " #Y )<<"  : "<<( (X)?"true":"false") <<std::endl;

int main()
{
  test(is_derived_from_Wrap <Int>::value, true);
  test(is_derived_from_Wrap <MyClass>::value, true);
  test(is_derived_from_Wrap <char>::value, false);
  test(is_derived_from_Wrap <X>::value, false);
}
```

This gives the expected output

```
is_derived_from_Wrap <Int>::value == true  : true
is_derived_from_Wrap <MyClass>::value == true  : true
is_derived_from_Wrap <char>::value == false  : false
is_derived_from_Wrap <X>::value == false  : false
```

There are a couple of gotchas with my code. It will also return true if the type is a Wrap.

```
assert(  is_derived_from_Wrap< Wrap<char> >::value == 1 );
```

This can probably be fixed using a bit more SFINAE magic if needed.

It will return false if the derivation is not a public derivation (i.e is private or protected )

```
struct Evil : private Wrap<T> { };
assert( is_derived_from_Wrap<Evil>::value == 0 );
```

I suspect this can't be fixed. (But I may be wrong ). But I suspect public inheritance is enough.

Comment: I suppose then that simple partial specialization as in my code won't work?

Comment: Correct as the specialisation will only match if the type matches exactly.
Your is_Wrap< Wrap<int> >::value = true, but is_Wrap<Int>::value = false.

Comment: Amazing. I used to think that `test_sfinae( Wrap<U> * w);` can not deduce `U` for the case of `X *`.

Answer (score 0):

The following determines whether something *is* a wrap:

```
template<class T>
struct is_Wrap { static const bool value = false; };

template<typename T> 
struct is_Wrap< Wrap<T> > { static const bool value = true; };
```

Since derivation is an Is-A relationship, everything derived from `Wrap<T>` also is a `Wrap<T>` and should be found by this.

Comment: My name `base of Wrap` is wrong. My bad english. `Derived from wrap`, of course.

Comment: It's not very good solution. Then I need to make DEFINE for the each class. I do not know all of them. I want to recognize whether X derived from Wrap<Y> where Y can be any type.

Comment: @Alexey: I'll try to adapt my code accordingly. But you definitely need to be more precise in asking your questions. (And that's not just a language barrier problem.)

Comment: This only tests if the type is exactly a Wrap<T>, rather than derived from.

Comment: @Michael; But isn't anythign derive from `Wrap<T>` also a `Wrap<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some fairly involved template metaprogramming to determine if one class X is derived from another Y, in the general case.   Basically X derives from Y if:

1. Y can be implicitly converted to X
2. X and Y are not the same type

[Andrei Alexandrescu](http://erdani.com/) explains how to do this (along with many other template tricks) in his book "Modern C++ Design".

You can find code which solves your problem either in the [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) library, or the [uSTL](http://ustl.sourceforge.net/) implementation, both written by Alexandrescu.

Comment: Having re-read the question, I realise that my suggestion doesn't solve the problem.  We don't want to know whether X derived from Y, but whether X derives from Y<T>, where T can be any type.

Comment: Yes. Your answer is not solution. But you have realized the problem.

Comment: You could also cite boost::is_base_of<Base, Derived> (which doesn't address the OP's issue since the Base parameter cannot be a class template).